Why do my shared objects have versioned @GLIBCXX symbols?
I am building a library whose output is an .so file.
When I run nm -u on it, I get the following:
nm -u libmycodec.so | grep invalid_argument
                 U _ZNSt16invalid_argumentC1EPKc
                 U _ZNSt16invalid_argumentC1ERKSs@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZNSt16invalid_argumentD1Ev@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZSt24__throw_invalid_argumentPKc@GLIBCXX_3.4
                 U _ZTISt16invalid_argument@GLIBCXX_3.4

On a different .so file on my system, I do not see versioned symbols. Example this is Pytorch's libtorch.so:
nm -u libtorch.so | grep invalid_argument
                 U _ZNSt16invalid_argumentD1Ev
                 U _ZTVSt16invalid_argument


From my rudimentary understanding, versioned GLIBCXX symbols make a .so file "picky" about what libstdc++.so file is installed on the user's system. Though the versioned symbols are there for a reason -- probably to ensure we never load an .so file older than that version maybe because of a bug fix?
My question is why do some modern libraries avoid using versioned symbols (like libtorch.so)?
And how do I make my .so file less picky about the libstdc++.so version that's installed on the user's system? Is it a combination of a compiler + linker flag?
I could statically link against libstdc++ but that may bloat up my .so file. Any other ideas on how to avoid a dependency on a specific version of libstdc++.so?

The way I ended up with is building with CentOS's devtoolset which uses system libstdc++ (say, from GCC9) and links newer symbols (say, from GCC12) statically.
